# Fixing type variables in locale extensions

Tags: polymorphism, isabelle, type-variables

Given this code

```
locale A =
  fixes foo :: "'a"

locale B = A +
  fixes bar :: "'a × 'a"

locale C' = A +
  fixes baz :: "'a"
begin
  sublocale B foo "(foo, baz)".
end
```

I get

```
Type unification failed

Failed to meet type constraint:

Term:  (foo, baz) :: 'b × 'a
Type:  'b × 'b
```

so it seems that Isabelle does not understand that `baz` and `foo` should be of the same type. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your declaration of locales `B` and `C`. The declaration for `B` is equivalent to the following

```
locale B = A foo for foo +
  fixes bar :: "'a * 'a"
```

Locales imports only remember the names of the parameters, but not the names of type variables. Thus, as you have not specified the type for `foo`, the most general type for `B`'s parameter is the following:

```
 foo :: 'b
 bar :: 'a * 'a
```

You can see this using the command `print_locale B`. The same happens in the declaration of locale `C`.

If you want to have the same type for `foo` and `bar`, you have to make the connection explicit in the locale declarations. There are two ways to do this.

```
locale B = A foo
  for foo :: 'a
  +
  fixes bar :: "'a * 'a"
```

and

```
locale B = A +
  constrains foo :: 'a
  fixes bar :: "'a * 'a"
```

Comment: Great, I didn’t know about `constrains`. Looks like I can even add sort constraints there (which would have been my next question).