# Why would adding a definition change type-correctness of a locale import?

Tags: type-inference, isabelle

Consider this example—note that `F1` and `F2` are identical.

```
theory Scratch  
  imports Main
begin

locale F0 =   
  fixes meaning :: ‹'model ⇒ 'a set›  ("⟦_⟧")

locale F1 = F0 +
  fixes γ :: ‹'a set ⇒ 'model›
  assumes sound: ‹L ⊆ ⟦γ L⟧›
  (* Typechecks. *)

definition (in F0) "models m L ≡ L ⊆ ⟦m⟧"  

locale F2 = F0 +
  fixes γ :: ‹'a set ⇒ 'model›
  assumes sound: ‹L ⊆ ⟦γ L⟧›
  (* Does not typecheck, see below. *)

end
```

The locale `F2`—which is the same as the well-typed `F1` except we've added a definition to `F0`—fails type-checking with the error message:

```
Type unification failed

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  meaning :: 'a ⇒ 'b set
Operand:   γ L :: 'model
```

Apparently, when type-checking `F2`, does the type checker suddenly decide that the free type variables `'a` and `'model` cannot be the same thing?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253538/fixing-type-variables-in-locale-extensions?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isabelle tools have a tendency to ‘normalize’ the names of type variables everywhere, including locales. When they do this, all type variables get replaced by `'a`, `'b`, `'c`, etc left-to-right. Apparently, the `definition` command somehow triggers this. Therefore, the `'a` and `'model` in `F0` suddenly become `'b` and `'a`.

If you want to override this, you can respecify the type variables explicitly:

```
locale F2 = F0 meaning
  for meaning :: "'model ⇒ 'a set" +
  fixes γ :: ‹'a set ⇒ 'model›
  assumes sound: ‹L ⊆ meaning (γ L)›
```

or

```
locale F2 = F0 +
  constrains meaning :: "'model ⇒ 'a set"
  fixes γ :: ‹'a set ⇒ 'model›
  assumes sound: ‹L ⊆ meaning (γ L)›
```

Comment: This is the part that I find slightly odd: "Apparently, the definition command somehow triggers this.". Would it not be useful to make this behavior more predictable? I guess, the problem is not very insignificant... (note: there was a typographical error in my original comment).

Comment: I find this annoying as well, but there's probably a reason behind all of this. I don't know much about the internals of locales. You could ask on the isabelle-users mailing list, but my guess is that you will only get the answer ‘This is working as intended’.